# If I have different UI controls to display sequentially, should I still use a table view controller?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I want to implement something similar to this- (focus on the left portion)

[image: example]

I imagine possible implementations to be

- Making a table view with (in this case) 7 'normal' cells, one normal size cell with a custom right accessory item, one 3XL cell containing a button, and finally a normal size cell with an imageview and custom accessory item.

or

- Making a scroll view with styled view containing UILabels masquerading as 'cells', a button within a larger UIView, and another faux view-with-label-cell.

Considering the challenges posed by different screen sizes, and the want for easy configuration and modification- which way should mixed sequential data be displayed? Hacky table view, redundant scroll view, or reinvented custom UIView?

**Edits**

I am currently using a sliding view controller. The sliding functionality is of no worry to me, the contents of the scroll/table view within is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found more information on this, and I definitely overcomplicated a simple matter.

The answer is yes (use the table view), and there are multiple reasons- the first being the principle of always using the highest level of abstraction where practical.

Static`UITableViewCells`are completely capable of rendering other UI elements (buttons, sliders, etc) inside themselves from stock, and this is encouraged in [Apple's UITableView spec](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html). Dynamic cells, stock, are not as flexible but they can be subclassed from `UITableViewCell` for more custom functionality.

To speak for the example, the first X (in this case, 7) cells are likely dynamic, and the last 3 cells are static. The 'second to last' cell seems to have an infinite(?) height, and the last cell appears to be a sticky tableview footer.

Answer (score 1):

There are various open source libraries available on net/github. you can use this https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController.

Although you can make your own if you want but doing this using scrollview I don't think it will be a good way to do that.

**Edit**

You basically have to create 8 normal cells and change the color of the cell label which is selected. And create a footer view of YUTableview for last view.

Comment: You posted just before I hit enter on a comment to the other answerer. I've already incorporated a sliding view controller into my app, the one you mentioned in fact. The sliding view controller is not my problem- organizing +-5 cells, a UIButton, and a touchable UILabel into a list view is.

Comment: you can implement this as an normal UITableView, what's the problem?

Comment: I'm finding out its less of a problem than I thought, just a matter of going through the implementation details for custom cells.

Comment: Much more on point. Glad you pointed out the footer, was thinking it was just another cell until I thought about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Slide-Out Navigation Panel. Use this [slide-out-navigation](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32054/how-to-create-a-slide-out-navigation-like-facebook-and-path) for better understanding.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already using ECSlidingViewController and it works just fine. My question is asking how I should put different UI elements into a sequential view, and how to manage proper cell/view sizing across different screen sizes.